# Big database, many maps?

Tags: java, database

As part of a student project I am building a large database, which could theoretically contain millions of objects.

I'm starting with the firstname (i.e. Person fName = "John").

My plan is to convert "John" to a hashcode, convert the hashcode into an Integer, then store it in the map as  - (as integer comparisons are faster).

Now here is my problem - To make the iteration faster, I want to have separate static maps, accessed depending on the first letter of the name.  Like

```
public class FirstNameList {

    private static Map<Integer, String> a = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> b = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> c = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    // etc

    public void addFName(String word) {
        if (word.length() == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No name entered");
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        char x = word.charAt(0);

        Integer i = word.hashCode();

        x-correctMap.put(i, word);
    }
```

However it does not feel very efficient to have 26 if statements to pick the correct list.  Does anyone know a way to pick the correct map? Or just better ideas in general?

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil". You don't have an issue but you need a solution. Keep it simple.

Comment: If you are keying on strings there is a data structure called a *ternary tree* that is good for that. You can find more info on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree), and there is a [blog post](http://trasahin.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/concurrent-ternary-search-tree.html) about implementing it in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have three suggestions: the first is a direct answer to your question:

- First, you could store your maps in a map with the initial character as a key, then simply look up the correct map in the "master map."
- Second, this won't be any faster -- likely slower -- than simply storing everything in a single map. Never assume you're more clever than the authors of a library class without measurements to prove there's a problem.
- Third, you said "database", so why not use a database instead of all this? Postgres and MySQL are both free and easy to use, and will serve your needs well.

Comment: Thanks.  The third option is something I'll look into at a later point, but sticking with the map I presumed that having smaller maps to iterate through would be quicker once the buckets got to a certain size.  Cheerfully withdrawn!

Comment: @Geo1986 -- `HashMap` will "rehash" itself by changing the number of buckets to keep the load factor below a threshold you can set.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest your maps, key of first map is for letter.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a list of maps, but you likely don't want to use a map at all. Something like TreeMap or a trie would work better, and allow you to have a single data structure.

Also, taking the hashcode of a string and then hashing is likely to be no faster than just using a String.

Comment: dfb I thought the conversion to an integer would make it faster for the equals in the map then comparing 2 strings which may make a difference if the bucket was thousands in size, is there no performance advantage?  Would a treemap be suitable for quickly getting the element if it was a size in the millions?